# How to call multiple intents at once when the slot value is shared by multiple intents?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

For example, I have a skill that tells the user about food interactions with medications. The user tells Alexa which medication they want to know about.

Each intent corresponds to a different medication interaction (e.g., grapefruit juice, antacids, etc.). Under the GrapefruitDrugs slot-type, I have several slot values (all of them are drug names). When the GrapefruitIntent is called, it gives the user a warning about this interaction. The problem is that I have other slot-types that share the same drugs and their warnings also need to be communicated to the user.

'Drug X', however, will interact with both grapefruit juice AND antacids. So the slot-type AntacidDrugs also has 'Drug X' listed as a slot value. I want both intents to be called.

How do I make sure that both intents get called? I've looked into chaining intents, however I have yet to see an example other than one that links an intent to the LaunchRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Intents are here just to point out what kind of sentence you have received on your webhook. Webhook can be on lambda or can be your custom server (e.g. Java, PHP, NodeJs …). In any case, here is your code and logic. Here you know at what state your conversation is and how should given intent be interpreted.

So in some conversation states you will react the same for two intents, while in some cases you might interpret the same intent in two different ways.